# Laravel: Update a nested json object

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-6

I have a column in my db for saving a users' settings. This is what the data structure looks like:

```
{"email":{"subscriptions":"{\"Foo\":true,\"Bar\":false}"}}
```

I am using a vue toggle to change the status of each property (true/false). Everything seems to be working, however when I save, I am wiping out the structure and saving the updated values like this:

```
{\"Foo\":true,\"Bar\":false}"}
```

**php**

```
$user = auth()->user();
$array = json_decode($user->preferences['email']['subscriptions'], true);
dd($array);
```

The above gets me:

```
array:2 [
    "Foo" => true
    "Bar" => false
]
```

So far so good...

```
$preferences = array_merge($array, $request->all());

dd($preferences);
```

Gets me:

```
array:2 [
    "Foo" => true
    "Bar" => true
]
```

Great - the values are now picking up the values passed in from the axios request. Next up; update the user's data:

```
$user->update(compact('preferences'));
```

Now my data looks like this:

```
{"Foo":true,"Bar":true}
```

The values are no-longer nested; I've wiped out `email` and `subscriptions`.

I've tried this:

```
$user->update([$user->preferences['email']['subscriptions'] => json_encode($preferences)]);
```

But it doesn't seem to save the data. How can I use the `$preferences` variable to update the data - and keep the data nested correctly?

Comment: try encoding the entire structure, something like this, if preferences is the column name `$user->update([
    'preferences' => json_encode([
        'email' => [
            'subscriptions' => $preferences 
        ]) 
    ]
]);`

Comment: That was it! I was focusing so much on trying to keep the existing format. I'm getting other error(s) now, but this is the shove I needed to figure it out. Thank you very much! Mark your comment as the answer; I'll make sure to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array with the structure you want the resulting json to have. So, for this json:

```
{
    "email":{
        "subscriptions":{
                "Foo":true,
                "Bar":false
        }
    }
}
```

you can create an array like this:

```
[
    'email' => [
        'subscriptions' => [
            'Foo' => true,
            'Bar' => false
        ]
    ]
]
```

an then, encode the entire structure:

```
json_encode([ 
    'email' => [ 
        'subscriptions' => [
            'Foo' => true, 
            'Bar' => false
        ] 
    ] 
]);
```

So, in your code, as you already have the nested array in the $preferences variable, I think this should work:

```
$json_preferences = json_encode([ 
    'email' => [ 
        'subscriptions' => $preferences 
    ] 
]);
```

Then you can update the user 'preferences' attribute (just for example):

```
User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->update(['preferences' => $json_preferences]);
```

or

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->preferences = $json_preferences;
$user->save();
```