# How to update deep json data in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I need to update my data in json column.

## Code

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->input('productId'));
    $stock = $product->qty;
    $qty = $request->input('quantity');
    $userId = auth('api')->user()->id;
    
    if (!empty($qty)) {
        if ($qty < $stock) {

            $item = CartStorage::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
            $item->update([
                // I need this to happen
                // cart_data->quantity= $qty;
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'data' => $item,
                'success' => 'Updated'
            ]);

        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 'Your quantity request is larger than our stock.'
            ]);
        }
    } else{ // 1. if nothing is given
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'You need to input new quantity.'
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have all my data ready in controller and there is no issue with data, all I need is to update my json data mentioned in this part:

```
$item = CartStorage::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
$item->update([
  // I need this to happen
  // cart_data->quantity= $qty;
]);
```

**Database screenshot**

[image: one]

**Database data `cart_data` column**

```
"{
    \"name\":\"Option Product\",
    \"productId\":21,
    \"price\":\"370000\",
    \"quantity\":2,           ------> trying to update this value
    \"attributes\":{
        \"attr\":{
            \"name\":\"weight\",
            \"value\":\"2\"
        }
    },
    \"conditions\":[
        {
            \"name\":\"Colors\",
            \"value\":0
        }
    ]
}"
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: This answer may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653778/laravel-update-a-nested-json-object

Comment: Basically you're going to need to get the existing value of cart_data and update it, then set it back on the object before saving.

Comment: @musicnothing I did based on answer there and it wiped my database now my `card_data` column only has `{"quantity":4}` :/

Comment: Make sure you're getting `$item->cart_data` and updating that, not just setting it to `['quantity' => 4]`

Comment: @musicnothing would you mind share an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @Kurt Friars is good. If you needed to pull the CartStorage model for some reason and do other things with it, you could update the cart_data like this:

```
$item = CartStorage::findOrFail($request->input('id'));

// Do whatever else you need

$cartData = $item->cart_data;
$cartData['quantity'] = 4;

$item->update([
    'cart_data' => $cartData
]);
```

Comment: I get `Illegal string offset 'quantity'`

Comment: I don't know enough about what your CartStorage model looks like. I would expect `cart_data` to be cast to a collection or an array. What is the data type? Is it a JSON string?

Comment: `protected $casts = ['cart_data' => 'array',];` about data type i shared my database data

Comment: I'm confused as to why `'quantity'` is an illegal string offset. This behavior would seem to indicate that `cart_data` is a string

Comment: Something's odd here. If it's cast as an array, it shouldn't need to be decoded

Comment: this works `$cartData = json_decode($item['cart_data'], true);`

Comment: it's array but json array (so i guess json need decoding)

Answer (score 1):

You can [update JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updating-json-columns) directly in the query builder without retrieving it first, like so:

```
// Assuming pk on cart_storages is id
DB::table('cart_storages')
   ->where('id', $request->input('id'))
   ->update([
       'cart_data->quantity' => $qty,
   ]);
```

It is important to state the documentation declares "This operation is supported on MySQL 5.7+ and PostgreSQL 9.5+"

Comment: this `->where('id', $request->input('id'));` should be `->where('id', $request->input('id'))` and also I'm not sure using `->` in column name ever works `cart_data->quantity`

Comment: In update part you have `'cart_data->quantity' => $qty,` , `cart_data->quantity` will never gonna get `quantity` variable inside `cart_data` column

Comment: Ah, thanks. fixed the semi-colon, whats the issue with, cart_data->quantity? What database/version are you using?

Comment: As per the laravel documentation I linked to, that is the syntax for specifying nested data in a json column.

Comment: no it returns `data: 0` while it should be `data: {item}` and in database it doesnt get updated

Comment: Hmm. Try the other answer then I suppose. I will leave my answer here since it is the "laravel way" of doing this.